# To convert .wav audio file to .mp3 in flutter

Tags: flutter, audio, flutter-web, audio-streaming, flutter-audio-query

I have a feature to listen to audio files, I'm getting audio files in .wav format and takes too long to play audio. When i tried .mp3 file with same audio player its delay decreased.

Is there any way to convert .wav to .mp3 or any other approches?

```
 FFmpegKit.execute('-i $url output.mp3').then((session) async {
                                                        final returnCode = await session.getReturnCode();

                                                        if (ReturnCode.isSuccess(returnCode)) {
                                                     

                                                          // SUCCESS

                                                        } else if (ReturnCode.isCancel(returnCode)) {

                                                          // CANCEL

                                                        } else {
                                                       

                                                          // ERROR

                                                        }
                                                      })
```

Answer (score 0):

**ffmpeg** is a complete, cross-platform solution to record, ***convert*** and stream audio and video.

Here is a great [package](https://pub.dev/packages/ffmpeg_kit_flutter) that ports ffmpeg features to flutter

Below is a usage example of the package that converts a **input.wav** file to an **output.mp3** file:

```
import 'package:ffmpeg_kit_flutter/ffmpeg_kit.dart';

 FFmpegKit.execute('-i input.wav output.mp3').then((session) async {
   final returnCode = await session.getReturnCode();

   if (ReturnCode.isSuccess(returnCode)) {

     // SUCCESS

   } else if (ReturnCode.isCancel(returnCode)) {

     // CANCEL

   } else {

     // ERROR

   }
 });
```

You can easily convert between different file formats,

here is a link to the official [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) website if you want to learn more

Comment: i have tried that but at the time of conversion, it shows "Automatic encoder selection failed for output stream #0:0. Default encoder for format mp3 (codec mp3) is probably disabled. Please choose an encoder manually"

Comment: thanks for suggestion, but when i add this to dependency it shows package doesnt exist

Comment: sorry, Here is the package you should import : ffmpeg_kit_flutter_audio: 4.5.1 ,
with the _audio package at the end, since you want to convert from .wav to .mp3

Comment: yes, i have done like that, but still its doesnt converting," -i assets/audio/wavdemo.wav -c:v assets/output file2.mp3", i have tried by doing the same with asset file but no result shown.

Comment: try temporary path instead asset path for input and output files. To get temporary path of asset mp3 file use this package path_provider.

 final tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    final tempPath = tempDir.path;

Comment: How do I get converted raw file or url of the file?